# Windows 8 Metro style App installation

Tags: windows-8, windows-runtime, .net-4.5

I have x86 tablet running Windows 8  Pro and i am trying to install appx package created in RTM on it , i ran as administrator everything
but application is not getting installed and I am getting error
"The term "Add-AppxPackage"is not recognized as a name of cmdlet , function script file or operable program"
Is there nay solution to above problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you installed a Windows Store developer license on the target machine? See this link:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh696646(v=vs.110).aspx

After that you should be able to install your package. I've never done my installs with the appx binary. When you do a build of your app, the output should contain an appx file plus a folder with the name of your app. The way I do my installs is to copy the folder to the target machine. Inside the folder is a powershell script that you can run to install the app. The script is called 'Add-AppDevPackage.ps1' and I believe you need to run it from an elevated (admin) Powershell console.

Edit: are you running the command like this:

.\add-appdevpackage.ps1

(or use whatever name you script is, and note the dot slash in front)